# Puede una go rutine impedir que otra go rutine se ejecute?

Tags: go

Estoy practicando go rutines, mutex y channels en go. Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de que una rutina suelte el lock.
El problema sucede que al llegar una rutina al bloque de codigo con los locks, al llegar al unlock aun sigue ejecutandose impidiendo el paso de la otra rutina.
El codigo es el siguiente (no paso todo el codigo completo porque no es necesario):

```
var mut sync.Mutex

func main() {
    in := time.Now()
    run()
    f := time.Since(in)
    fmt.Println(f)
}

type Valores struct {
    tomarLista         int
    contadorSoluciones int
}

type ColaInicial struct {
    *Valores
    cola_inicial map[int][]int
}

type ColaFinal struct {
    *Valores
    cola_final map[int][]int
}

func run() {
    puzzleInicial := crearPuzzle(9)
    grafo := crearGrafo(9)
    puzzleFinal := crearRandom(puzzleInicial, grafo)
    cola_inicial := make(map[int][]int)
    cola_final := make(map[int][]int)
    cola_inicial[0] = append(cola_inicial[0], puzzleInicial...)
    cola_final[0] = append(cola_final[0], puzzleFinal...)
    var colI = ColaInicial{&Valores{0, 0}, cola_inicial}
    var colF = ColaFinal{&Valores{0, 0}, cola_final}
    done := make(chan bool)
    go busquedaBid(colI.cola_inicial, colF.cola_final, grafo, done, colI.tomarLista, colI.contadorSoluciones)
    go busquedaBid(colF.cola_final, colI.cola_inicial, grafo, done, colF.tomarLista, colF.contadorSoluciones)
    <-done
}

func busquedaBid(cola map[int][]int, colaCheck map[int][]int,
    grafo map[int][]int, done chan bool,tomarLista int, 
    contadorSoluciones int) {
    for {
        mut.Lock()
        nodo := getIndex(cola[tomarLista])
        for _, neighbour := range grafo[nodo] {
            sliceAux := append([]int(nil), cola[tomarLista]...)
            valorAux := sliceAux[neighbour]
            indCero := getIndex(sliceAux)
            sliceAux[neighbour] = 0
            sliceAux[indCero] = valorAux
            booleanVal := checkRepetitionsMapSlice(cola, sliceAux)
            if !booleanVal {
                contadorSoluciones += 1
                cola[contadorSoluciones] = sliceAux
            }
        }
        tomarLista += 1
        mut.Unlock()
        if checkEqualityValues(cola, colaCheck) {
            close(done)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

El error sucede en el siguiente espacio de codigo:

```
for {
        mut.Lock()
        nodo := getIndex(cola[tomarLista])
        for _, neighbour := range grafo[nodo] {
            sliceAux := append([]int(nil), cola[tomarLista]...)
            valorAux := sliceAux[neighbour]
            indCero := getIndex(sliceAux)
            sliceAux[neighbour] = 0
            sliceAux[indCero] = valorAux
            booleanVal := checkRepetitionsMapSlice(cola, sliceAux)
            if !booleanVal {
                contadorSoluciones += 1
                cola[contadorSoluciones] = sliceAux
            }
        }
        tomarLista += 1
        mut.Unlock()
        if checkEqualityValues(cola, colaCheck) {
            close(done)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Llega la rutina, toma el lock, ejecuta el codigo correspondiente y a llegar al unlock, sigue ejecutandose, tomando el lock de nuevo impidiendo la ejecucion de la otra rutina.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es como estás utilizando los mecanismos de orquestación de programación concurrente que ofrece go.

La estructura de bucle `for` proporcionada en la función `busquedaBid` bloquea y desbloquea en cada iteración, pero si el bucle se ejecuta lo **suficientemente rápido**, la misma goroutine podría adquirir el bloqueo de nuevo antes de que la otra tenga la oportunidad de tomarlo. Esta situación puede generar **starvation** a la otra gorutine, especialmente si el trabajo dentro del bloqueo **es mínimo y rápido de ejecutar**.

Para resolver este problema, un enfoque es introducir cierta equidad en el mecanismo de bloqueo o forzar a la gorutine a ceder después de desbloquear. Dado que `sync.Mutex` no garantiza la equidad (no se garantiza que una goroutine en espera sea la siguiente en obtener el bloqueo después de que se libere), puede que necesites reestructurar tu código o utilizar otros mecanismos de sincronización. Aquí tienes una posible solución utilizando `channels` para controlar el acceso, lo que puede proporcionar la equidad necesaria:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// ... variables y resto de declaraciones ...

// semáforo es un channel que permitirá que sólo una goroutine acceda a la sección crítica
var semaphore = make(chan struct{}, 1)

func run() {
    // ... codigo de inicializacion ...

    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        semaphore <- struct{}{} // Acquire token
        busquedaBid(colI.cola_inicial, colF.cola_final, grafo, done, colI.tomarLista, colI.contadorSoluciones)
        <-semaphore // Release token
    }()
    go func() {
        semaphore <- struct{}{} // Acquire token
        busquedaBid(colF.cola_final, colI.cola_inicial, grafo, done, colF.tomarLista, colF.contadorSoluciones)
        <-semaphore // Release token
    }()
    <-done
}

func busquedaBid(cola map[int][]int, colaCheck map[int][]int,
    grafo map[int][]int, done chan bool, tomarLista int,
    contadorSoluciones int) {
    // ... resto de codigo ...
}

// ... otras funciones ...

func main() {
    in := time.Now()
    run()
    f := time.Since(in)
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

Este cambio utiliza un `buffered channel` como semáforo, asegurando que sólo una goroutine puede entrar en la sección crítica a la vez. Cuando la goroutine termina su trabajo, libera el token leyendo del canal, lo que da a otra goroutine la oportunidad de proceder.

Recuerda que la introducción de cualquier tipo de sincronización o control de concurrencia puede alterar potencialmente el comportamiento de tu programa, por lo que es importante probar a fondo estos cambios para asegurarse de que resuelven el problema sin introducir nuevos problemas.